# Tensorflow dataset pipeline with specific classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I would like to use a dataset pipeline with specific class indexes.

- For example:

if I use CIFAR-10 Dataset. I can load the dataset as follows:

```
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
```

Which load all the class labels (10 Classes). I can create a pipeline using the following code:

```
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train)).batch(64)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_test,y_test)).batch(64)
```

This works well for the training Keras model.

- Now I want to create a pipeline with a few samples (Instead of using all 10 class samples maybe use only 5 samples). Is there any way to make a pipeline like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.data.Dataset.filter`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#filter):

```
import tensorflow as tf

class_indexes_to_keep = tf.constant([0, 3, 4, 6, 8], dtype=tf.int64)

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()

y_train = y_train.astype(int)
y_test = y_test.astype(int)
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train)).filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_any(y == class_indexes_to_keep)).batch(64)
test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_test,y_test)).filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_any(y == class_indexes_to_keep)).batch(64)
```

To convert to categorical labels, you could try:

```
import tensorflow as tf

one_hot_encode = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(tf.range(10, dtype=tf.int64), num_classes=10)
class_indexes_to_keep = tf.gather(one_hot_encode, tf.constant([0, 3, 4, 6, 8], dtype=tf.int64))

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = tf.keras.datasets.cifar10.load_data()
y_train = y_train.astype(int)

train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train,y_train)).map(lambda x, y: (x, tf.one_hot(y, 10)[0]))
train_dataset = train_dataset.filter(lambda x, y: tf.reduce_any(tf.reduce_all(y == class_indexes_to_keep, axis=-1))).batch(64)
```

Comment: Hello AloneTogether,
Thank you for your reply! The code is giving me and error! saying:

TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Equal' Op has type int32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'.

Comment: Does `class_indexes_to_keep = tf.constant([0, 3, 4, 6, 8], dtype=tf.int32)` work ? @tasrif

Comment: It works now!
Also, changing
```y_train = y_train.astype('int64')```

```y_test = y_test.astype('int64')```
does the work

Comment: Alos, Can I convert a class vector (integers) to binary class matrix wiht this pipeline?

Such as using ```tf.keras.utils.to_categorical```

Comment: Yes definitely, but you have to make sure that your integers start from zero until n. See updated answer.